# Properly splitting up code for SQL Database in CodeFirst

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a little problem with my database design in an EntityFramework6 project. These are my two code first classes I use to create the database with. As you can see the Details class violates all normal forms out there and I want to split it up properly, however I have no idea how to do it properly, since I am totally new to SQLServer and EF.
So what is the best way to get a decent database design which I then could query?

```
internal class LocationDataContract
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

    public LocationsDetailsDataContract Details { get; set; }
}

internal class LocationDetailsDataContract
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Location")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Planet { get; set; }

    public bool? IsCapital { get; set; }

    public int Population { get; set; }

    public string System { get; set; }

    public string Sector { get; set; }

    public LocationDataContract Location { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Updated Question below**

So following the advice of George I did the following. Would this be a decent solution. I Have to add, that I need to to some converting since the application uses different (completely inheritance based) models, which I have to use since a database is not the only source of data and said data uses yet *another* format to store data which I can't change.

```
internal class LocationDataContract
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

    public LocationsDetails Details { get; set; }
}

internal abstract class LocationDetailDataContract
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Location")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }}

    public LocationsDetails Details { get; set; }
}

internal class CityDetailDataContract : LocationDetailDataContract
{

    public string Planet { get; set; }

    public bool? IsCapital { get; set; }

    public int Population { get; set; }
}

internal class PlantDetailDataContract : LocationDetailDataContract
{
    public int Population { get; set; }

    public string System { get; set; }
}

internal class SystemDetailDataContract : LocationDetailDataContract
{
    public string Sector { get; set; }
}

internal class SectorDetailDataContract : LocationDetailDataContract
{
    // For now nothing
}
```

Comment: Why dont you create new classes for properties like Planet, System and Sector to normalize the database?

Comment: @George I updated the original question. Was this what you meant?

Comment: see my answer for what i meant...

Answer (score 0):

@Ruhrpottpatriot, why all classe are inheriting from LocationDetailDataContract? 
Doing this i believe you will have a buch of classes and tables but the data will remain desnormalized (ex: CityDetailDataContract will have the column Planet with repeated strings.

Are you allowed to do something like this from you original question?

```
internal class LocationDataContract
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }

    public LocationDetailsDataContract Details { get; set; }
}

internal class LocationDetailsDataContract
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Location")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Planet Planet { get; set; }

    public System System { get; set; }

    public Sector Sector { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public LocationDataContract Location { get; set; }
}

internal class Planet {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool? IsCapital { get; set; }

    public int Population { get; set; }
}

internal class System {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
internal class Sector {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```